dispersion of a negative binomial model
In R's, glm.nb summary, it says dispersion parameter $\phi$ is set to 1. When the model is
$Y \sim \text{Negbin}(\mu,\theta)$
where $E(Y)=\mu$ and $V(Y)=\mu+\mu^2/\theta$. Is it correct that dispersion $\phi$ here means  $V(Y)=\phi(\mu+\mu^2/\theta)$ in the exponential family formulation? Given that $\theta$ can be freely adjusted, does it make sense to test, e.g., $H_0: \phi=1$? I know negative binomial models may not fit well to data for various reasons (e.g., relationship between many zeros and other values), but if we say it is overdispersion, we also need to consider overdispersion for a normal distribution, but it is often stated there is no overdispersion in gaussian models.
set.seed(1)
x <- round(rep(seq(3,30,by=3),each=10))
y <- rnbinom(length(x),mu=exp(1+0.1*x),size=5)

plot(x,y)
library(MASS)
model <- glm.nb(y~x)
r <- resid(model,type="pearson")
(phi <- sum(r^2)/(length(x)-3)) # dispersion

Similar post: link

The dispersion parameter $\phi$ is set by default to 1 when running summary on a glm.nb object, and it basically means nothing. It is only informative for Poisson and Binomial families. Check this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70619/dispersion-in-summary-glm

I believe that $\phi$ is simply not a parameter of the model fitted (see the MASS book), so it is meaningless to estimate it or test it. The model fitted with glm.nb uses a glm "fitter" function for which $\phi$ makes sense, but it is not used here.

@Yves why does $\phi$ makes sense for glm but not for glm.nb?

I think that $\phi$ makes sense for some glms such as the Gaussian. But the model implemented in glm.nb is not a GLM in the classical definition since it involves a shape parameter $\theta$ which is estimated. It would be confusing to call $\theta$ a  dispersion parameter although it controls the index of dispersion via $\text{ID} = 1 + \mu / \theta$. I can not see what would be the likelihood for a kind of generalized negative model that would use an extra third parameter $\phi$.

@Yves "I can not see what would be the likelihood for". There is no true likelihood function with all those parameters. It is a quasi-likelihood function. The glm.nb fits a model by varying the parameter $\theta$, after that we can use a goodness of fit test to test whether the sum of squared residuals is a lot larger or smaller than expected.

@SextusEmpiricus But what is the distribution of the response $y$ conditional on $x$ according to this model?

@Yves that distribution doesn't exist. That is why it is a quasi-likelihood method, because it is not a real likelihood function based on a real existing distribution.

@Yves in my answer I wrote $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(y_i-\mu_i)^2}{V(\mu_i)} \sim Gamma(\nu,\phi)$ but now I am actually starting to doubt this. There is a sum of many terms and for a large amount of $n$ the central limit theorem plays a role. But I wonder whether we can assume a gamma distribution for small $n$ (this makes me think of this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/645462/645633 with a kurtosis based correction factor for the F-test)

Your primary question seems to be this one:

Given that $\theta$ can be freely adjusted, does it make sense to test, e.g., $H_0: \phi = 1$?

Two methods one can use for the Poisson are the score test and Lagrange multiplier tests. I might be wrong, but I imagine these can be generalized to a degree to an negative binomial model. A score test is a post-hoc test which tests whether the hypothesis of no overdispersion can be rejected:
$$
z = \frac{(y - \mu)^2 - y}{\mu\sqrt{2}}
$$
where $\mu$ is the predicted response and $y$ is the raw response. You basically fit a regular NB model, take the predictions from that model, and then solve for $z$:
#### Load Data ####
library(COUNT)
data(rwm5yr)
rwm1984 <- subset(rwm5yr, year==1984) 

#### Fit NB Model ####
nb <- glm.nb(
  docvis ~ outwork + age, 
  data=rwm1984
)

#### Get Mu ####
mu <- predict(nb, type="response")

#### Estimate Z ####
z <- ((rwm1984$docvis - mu)^2 - rwm1984$docvis)/ (mu * sqrt(2))
summary(zscore <- lm(z ~ 1))

The t-test from the intercept ($t = 7.082$, $p < .001$) shows the "no dispersion" hypothesis can be rejected. However, this test typically runs with the assumption that the dataset is large. One can alternatively use the Lagrange multiplier test instead, which is defined as:
$$
\chi^2 = \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu^2_i-n \bar{y}_i\right)^2}{2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu^2_i}
$$
Estimated as so:
#### Setup Formula for Chi ####
obs <- nrow(rwm1984)
mmu <- mean(mu)
nybar <- obs*mmu
musq <- mu*mu
mu2 <- mean(musq)*obs 

#### Chi Square Estimation ####
chival <- (mu2 - nybar)^2/(2*mu2)
chival

#### P Value ####
pchisq(chival,1,lower.tail = FALSE)

Once again, the hypothesis is rejected, with a fairly large chi-square score. Keep in mind that if you just want to get the dispersion from the model, this function can do that quite easily, and was created specifically for glm.nb fits in the msme package but written explicitly here:
#### Create Dispersion Function ####
p_disp <- function(x) {
  pr <- sum(residuals(x, type = "pearson")^2)
  dispersion <- pr/x$df.residual
  return(c(pearson.chi2 = pr, dispersion = dispersion))
}

#### Check ####
p_disp(nb)

Where you can see the dispersion is clearly above 1. More about these tests can be found in the below reference.
Reference
Hilbe, J. M. (2014). Modeling count data. Cambridge Univ. Press.


we also need to consider overdispersion for a normal distribution, but it is often stated there is no overdispersion in gaussian models.

This can be related to the following difference:

For the normal distribution, there is intrinsically a dispersion parameter, the squared standard deviation $\sigma^2$.
For the negative binomial distribution there is not such a parameter. The plain negative binomial distribution doesn't have a dispersion parameter.

The addition of a dispersion parameter is artificial. In the framework of generalized linear models if the score function (which is used to compute the maximum likelihood) does not yet have a dispersion parameter, then we can add an additional dispersion parameter.
With this adjustment, the resulting score function does not need to relate to an actual existing distribution and likelihood function. It is called a quasi-likelihood function.
For those cases, when this  dispersion parameter is not normally part of the actual distribution (e.g. the binomial distribution, Poisson distribution and negative binomial distribution), there we call it over-dispersion when the variance is larger than expected. A good example case of the opposite, under-dispersion is: A chart of daily cases of COVID-19 in a Russian region looks suspiciously level to me - is this so from the statistics viewpoint?

Where does this dispersion parameter fit in?
For many GLM models, the score is a simple function of the difference between the observation and the mean, divided by a function for the variance that is a function solely of the mean.
$$s(y;\mu) = \frac{\partial \log[\mathcal{L}(y,\mu]}{\partial \mu} = \frac{y-\mu}{V(\mu)}$$
Several GLM models can have an additional dispersion parameter, then the score looks like
$$s(y;\mu) = \frac{\partial \log[\mathcal{L}(y,\mu]}{\partial \mu} = \frac{y-\mu}{\phi V(\mu)}$$
For distributions like Poisson or Binomial distribution this parameter is not in the model and we can say $\phi = 1$. For example,

with a Bernoulli distribution $V(\mu) = \mu(1-\mu)$ and $$s(y;\mu) = \frac{y-\mu}{\mu(1-\mu)}$$
with a Poisson distribution $V(\mu) = \mu$ and $$s(y;\mu) = \frac{y-\mu}{\mu}$$

And we could come up with quasi-likelihood models like $s(y;\mu) = \frac{y-\mu}{\phi\mu(1-\mu)}$ and $s(y;\mu) = \frac{y-\mu}{\phi\mu}$, then the parameter $\phi$ relates to under or over-dispersion and we are modelling as if the distribution is something that resembles Poisson or Binomial/Bernoulli but with a different (larger or smaller) variance.


does it make sense to test, e.g., $H_0: \phi=1$?

You can do that. The GLM model can be fitted independently from estimating the dispersion parameter. After estimating the GLM model, the dispersion parameter is fitted based on the sum of squared residuals divided by the function $V(\mu)$
$$\hat\phi = \frac{1}{n-m} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i-\hat\mu_i)^2}{V(\hat\mu_i)}$$
See also: Is there a Relationship Between Variance and Chi-Square?
For large $n$ this is approximately normal distributed and the variance might be estimated with the kurtosis of the distribution of the residuals. (F-test for equality of variance for truncated normal distributions)

Could you please provide references and/or examples
for the benefits of using $\phi$ for estimation/inference? This seems to be discussed in Sec. 2.3.1 in James K Lindey's book. It can be misleading to relate the dispersion parameter $\phi$ to
overdispersion: the marginal distribution of an overdispersed model
being different from the original one, see sections 2.3.2 and 3.3.2
in Lindley's book in relation with conjugate priors.

Also, in the code of MASS::neg.bin there is no such thing as $\phi$ and the fit is based
on the plain likelihood using $\phi=1$ being only a coding artefact.

@Yves Yes, the plain negative binomial distribution doesn't have a dispersion parameter, so it is not surprising that MASS::neg.bin doesn't include or . But, we can define a quasi-likelihood function that does have this dispersion parameter.

@Yves the parameter $\phi$ is indeed not directly an 'overdispersion parameter' but instead a 'dispersion parameter'. I don't believe that is is misleading to call a misfit of the data due to a larger dispersion, over-dispersion, although it might be true that there can be many reasons for the misfit, some of which are not really over-dispersion. (e.g. a wrong model for the mean will lead to larger residuals)

I agree. Since there is no parameter $\phi$ is the model, rather than
testing $\phi = 1$, the test is a kind of lack-of-fit test using
$\widehat{\phi}$ as test statistic.

@Yves given that one doesn't agree on the quasi-likelihood functions, one might still agree about discrepancies of the deviance (which can be partemerized by $\phi$) and related statistical tests. This thread of comments relates to "The conditions under which $\chi^2$ measures the discrepancy between observation and hypothesis" Fisher 1924

Thank you for the reference and this interesting discussion, maybe originating with problems of vocabulary.

Ignore what summaries with $\theta = 1$ say and with a reasonable amount of data you can estimate $\theta$ from the data. The dispersion parameter $\theta$ in this parameterization is describing how the model deviates from a Poisson distribution (how much it is overparameterized). For $\theta \to \infty$ the distribution increasingly becomes like a Poisson distribution.
Doing a test vs. "$\theta = \infty$" is a bit tricky, because it's not a finite parameter value and it's also on the edge of the parameter space, which makes many things like confidence intervals etc. tricky (and that doesn't change if you use the paramterization used by SAS, which uses $\kappa := 1/\theta$ instead - although that makes it easier to deal with $\hat{\kappa}=0$). However, even with R's parameterization you could e.g. test for it being so high a value that it's almost a Poisson distribution anyway. I.e. null hypothesis it's a negative binomial with meaningful overdispersion vs. Poisson, say, $\theta < \theta_0$ for some relatively large $\theta_0$ and alternative that it's pretty close to a Poisson $\theta \geq \theta_0$.
There's of course other existing tests for overdispersion.

The question is about the dispersion parameter $\phi$, whereas this answer speaks about $\theta$. This is confusing.
